# Align 3 UIButtons to the bottom centre of UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uibutton, autolayout

I have a `UIViewController` that consists of a `UIImageView` then I want to provide three options to user namely, rotate, crop, draw.

I want these three buttons to remain always centred at the bottom and maintain an exact distance with the `UIImageView`.

How can achieve this using auto layout I have done a lot of search as well as work but to no good use.

[image]

Comment: In portrait orientation only? show your storyboard screenshot that how you exact want that buttons

Comment: No on rotation as well

Comment: add screenshot of that viewcontroller from storyboard for better understanding

Comment: I have added a screenshot of how I want it to be

Comment: These buttons are on toolbar?

Comment: No they are not I have just added them on the view controller

Comment: @AvinashSharma i have edited answer with demo. please check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set constrain like this ,

First set Constrain to centre button(Crop Button). like,

**Crop button :-** Bottom spacing from bottomlayout , height and width (According to your requirement), and Centre Horizontally in container (now your crop button is fix in centre)

**Rotatebutton:-** set Horizontal spacing from crop button , rotate buttons top=cropbuttons top , rotate button's bottom=crop buttons bottom , and Rotate button's height and width equal to  Crop button's Height and Width.

(set constrain to draw button same as rotate button)

So, all button's look same .

check in image ,

1) Set constrain to Buttons

[image]

2) Now set constrain to imageview

[image]

3) Output

[image]

**Edit :-** Here i have attached demo ,

[Demo for Centre button](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=01247460525311045298)

Answer (score 2):

(1) First add ImageView, constraints like this

[image]

(2) now add an `UIButton` in the bottom center named **CROP**. Give Constraints like this

[image]                                    [image]

(3) Now add 2 `UIButtons` named **ROTATE** and **DRAW** on either side of **CROP**

for **ROTATE:** [image]
 for **DRAW:** [image]

(4) Finally select 3 buttons and give **equalWith** Constraint

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No need to add Constraint to with ImageView. Add these buttons on a UIView and add the constraint on that view as Horizontally Center and also add ImageView on a UIView. Now add the constraintHorizontally Center on the parent view of Button to the parent of ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario should be like below,

left most button should have two constraints(cancel) : leading,bottton

right most button should have two constrains (yellow button) : trailing,bottom

Take one `UIVIew` and put thhree buttons in that view with equal distance from every side of that `uiview`.

now your constraints to all three buttons should like : leading,trailing,top and fixed height

And constraints of that `uiview` should be : horizontally center in container, bottom and fixed height

I am attaching screenshot aswell

[image]

You can check constraints from view hierarchy on left side.

I have set gray background color to just demonstrate this is view you not need to set color of that view.

By this way your three buttons will always display to bottom center of your VC

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below steps might fix the buttons the way you wanted.Have not tried myself but you can try out if you have not tested these steps.

1.Pin those buttons to the bottom space container
2.Add a constraint from button to top space to image view 
3.Play around horizontal spaces between buttons by pinning leading edge to the view for the left most button and trailing space to the view from right most button
4.Check center horizontally/vertically to the container